# Record Type Not changing if opportunity name has # key

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have 5 record types in case object and following is the code that i used for the list button in order to choose record type and create case.

```
setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&save_new_url= 
%2F500%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F
{!Opportunity.Id}%26CF00N3600000VTBx_lkid 
%3D{!Opportunity.Id}%26CF00N3600000VTBx%3D{!Opportunity.Name}
```

If the opportunity Name contains "#" key, Whatever record type i select it redirects to the default record type. It works perfectly fine if there is no "#" in the opportunity name. Also I am creating the case from opportunity. Please help me fix this.

Comment: # is special character which break the URL. Try to encode it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you {!URLENCODE(Opportunity.Name)}

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained _why_ your proposed solution should work. Also, for simple things like this, it's a good idea to try it for yourself in a sandbox to make sure that it does, in fact, work.

Answer (score -1):

Create a workflow rule on creation of case object, in criteria use contains function to check it name contains a #.
In action assign record type you want .

Check this link to example of contains keyword

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004749&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Thank You for the answer Amit, But the problem is I should be able to select any 1 of the 5 record types. Requirement is not to select a particular record type based on the # key